# How can I resolve Google reporting "This site may harm your computer" for my website?

Tags: google-search

Google is reporting that 'This site may harm your computer' for my website. How can I resolve this issue?

> Of the 17 pages we tested on the site over the past 90 days, 2 page(s) resulted in malicious software being downloaded and installed without user consent. The last time Google visited this site was on 2013-07-26, and the last time suspicious content was found on this site was on 2013-07-26.
>
> Malicious software is hosted on 3 domain(s), including qygjutwojtgdntqidubw.dnsalias.com/, wink.ie/, 3xindiansex.com/.
>
> 2 domain(s) appear to be functioning as intermediaries for distributing malware to visitors of this site, including wink.ie/, 3xindiansex.com/.
>
> This site was hosted on 1 network(s) including AS21844 (THEPLANET-AS).

Comment: Are you on a shared host?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that of the 17 pages on the site, 2 pages had links to one or several of the 3 domains qygjutwojtgdntqidubw.dnsalias.com, wink.ie and 3xindiansex.com, domains that host malicious software.

This probably happens either because you link to them, or, or you link to some iframe or javascript that links to them, or because you are on a shared domain where other sites link to them.